# Angular SSR with SSL is broken with the http client get for relative url

Tags: angular, angular-universal

```js
httpClient.get('assets/test.json')
```

It's working without SSL.

But it is broken after I use SSL.

The url becomes `https://undefined/assets/test.json`

How can I use relative url here?

Comment: can u paste rest part of code where the url is getting created

Comment: The url is just a relative path like this. It's not an absolute path. But it's working with SSR without SSL. But it is not working with SSR with SSL. SSR refer to Server Side Rendering.@AshishRatan

Comment: Sorry that I just mess up the two request. I try to use the simple  test.json relative url to load. And it's working without SSL in SSR. It's not working with SSL in SSR.

Comment: your post/question and comment has same value,  I was asking if u have given any customised logic to create path

Comment: No. I just use 'assets/test.json'. It's a relative url. And I didn't modify it. I just pass it to the httpClient.get method. But it's working with HTTP. But it's not working with HTTPS `ng serve --ssl`.